# In Objective-C, Euler's number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How could Euler's number (e) be implemented in Objective-C?

Answer (score 16):

`M_E`, declared in `<math.h>`, is the value of the Euler number. You can use the `exp()` function, also declared in `math.h` to calculate `e^x`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the constant `M_E` defined in `<math.h>` is what you are looking for.